# Craft 3 Plugin Index No Template Found

Tags: plugin-development

I'm looking to have a basic index page for my plugin, yet I can't seem to get `index.html` working for my plugin. But when I head to `site.local/admin/plugin` it displays `404 Template Not Found`

I have the folders set up like so:
`plugin/templates/index.html`

I've read here that CP templates automatically get set up for this folder so there's no need to define routes for it.

> Plugins get a Control Panel template root added automatically, named
>   after the plugin handle, which points to the templates/ folder within
>   the plugin’s base source folder.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

did you register the routes in your plugin's init() ?

Comment: ```        // Register a custom CP route
        Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $e) {
            $e->rules['/'] = ['template' => 'putter/index'];
        });```